# Soft phone not getting register to my asterisk server

Tags: centos, asterisk, voip, sip

I have config in my local lan asterisk for test. which is working fine.

With the same OS version and packages on "AWS Cloud" I am setting as following. But it don't get register "error =  sip 408 - request timeout" same I am getting on all Iphone and Androids.

On my cloud all port are open TCP /UDP 1 to 65553

I have done following step to setup my asterisk server.

Kindly suggest us what went wrong with setting.

```
    uname -a
Linux mysip.guggle.co.in 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

vi /etc/hosts
209.179.132.XXX sip.guggle.co.in sip  ---> this is my static IP Address

vi /etc/sysconfig/network
HOSTNAME=guggle.co.in  ---> FQDN 

vi /etc/hostname
guggle.co.in

vi /etc/selinux/config
selinux=disabled
chkconfig iptables off
chkconfig ip6tables off


rpm -ivh http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/6Server/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-rawhide.noarch.rpm

cd /etc/yum.repos.d/ && wget http://packages.asterisk.org/centos/centos-asterisk-12.repo && wget http://packages.digium.com/centos/centos-digium-12.repo

cd /usr/src/ && wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-gui/asterisk-gui-2.1.0-rc1.tar.gz && tar zxvf asterisk-gui-2.1.0-rc1.tar.gz && cd asterisk-gui-2.1.0* && ./configure && make && make install && make checkconfig

cp -Rfv /var/lib/asterisk/* /usr/share/asterisk/ && mv /var/lib/asterisk /var/lib/asterisk_original && ln -s /usr/share/asterisk  /var/lib/asterisk

sudo yum install gcc bison flex zlib-devel openssl-devel httpd mysql-server mysql-devel krb5-libs e2fsprogs-devel keyutils-libs-devel  krb5-devel  libselinux-devel libsepol-devel  krb5-workstation mod_dav_svn subversion dahdi-linux dahdi-tools libpri asterisk

chkconfig asterisk on && chkconfig dahdi on && reboot

login as root :

cd /etc/asterisk

vi sip.conf

[raj]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=password ; put a strong, unique password here instead
context=users

[pjain]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=othersecretpassword ; put a strong, unique password here instead
context=users

[sham]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=password ; put a strong, unique password here instead
context=users

vi extension.conf

[users]
exten=>986001,1,Dial(SIP/raj,20)
exten=>986002,1,Dial(SIP/pjain,20)
exten=>986003,1,Dial(SIP/sham,20)

service asterisk restart

asterisk -rvvvvc

sip reload
sip show peers
dialplan reload
dialplan show users
http show status

http://guggle.co.in
```

Comment: The ports are open, but is your asterisk server listening on that external interface?

Comment: NickW Thank you so much for your reply, YES IP address is ping-able from each phone & default url page is getting loading. When we test same setting on our local LAN /WIFI it work. We are able to telnet on 5060 on our static ipaddress. Pink

Comment: So when you do a `netstat -an | grep :5060` you see something like `0.0.0.0:5060` listed?

Comment: yes on TCP/UDP I can see internal ipaddress from AWS. $ netstat -an |grep :5060
tcp        0      0 10.18.5.30:5060            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
udp        0      0 10.18.5.30:5060            0.0.0.0:*  $ telnet 209.132.179.120 5060
Trying 209.12.19.***...
Connected to 209.12.19.***.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Nothing at all in your asterisk logs?

Comment: no, To get this working on my URL planning setup DNS(bind9) will it work us?

Comment: Certainly, if you're not trying to get your softphones to connect via IP, and don't have the sipserver address published in DNS, you will have issues, unless the softphone machines have the DNS name in /etc/hosts. Make sure to publish a srv record as well. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DNS+SRV

Comment: NickW I have one question here from my above setup When we do it on our local LAN/WiFi how it work well. Because in my server /etc/hosts file done not have any entry from my iphone's and Android's /Laptop still is working. Same time from my AWS Cloud EC2 image I can resole www.siptesting.com to my all device's. And the same time we would like have our people can create they own account from the url like "tango". Let see after setting up BIND 9 it should work well.

Comment: On your LAN you either use IPs or have a local DNS server, I'd imagine.. as for setting up accounts, you'll probably need to move to an external Authentication and Authorization system, but that is something I'm not able to advise you on.